# MinGW pacman -Sys Unable to lock database

Tags: c++, installation, compiler-errors, mingw, msys2

To start Code and Compile C++, must install a compiler. For my case, it is **MSYS2** through which **MinGW** is available. According to the installation guild mentioned on the **[website](https://www.msys2.org/)**, I installed the software without any errors. Now I was supposed to update the package database and base packages by entering `pacman -Sys` but it has shown an error
`error: failed to synchronize all databases (unable to lock database)`

After searching online for a solution I found that deleting/removing the `db.lck` will work, for that, I used this command `rm /var/lib/pacman/db.lck`
but it showed another error. Right now there is no solution to this on the internet.
I've also pasted the terminal output of **MSYS2 MSYS** for refernce.

```
$ pacman -Sys
:: Synchronizing package databases...
error: failed to synchronize all databases (unable to lock database)

VIRAT@DESKTOP-97BS0AB MSYS ~
$ rm /var/lib/pacman/db.lck
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/pacman/db.lck': No such file or directory

VIRAT@DESKTOP-97BS0AB MSYS ~
$ pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
error: failed to init transaction (unable to lock database)
error: could not lock database: Permission denied

VIRAT@DESKTOP-97BS0AB MSYS ~
$ pacman -Su
error: failed to init transaction (unable to lock database)
error: could not lock database: Permission denied

VIRAT@DESKTOP-97BS0AB MSYS ~
$
```

Comment: Where doer your link suggest `pacman -Sys`?

Comment: The easiest solution is probably to reinstall MSYS2.

Comment: i did re install it 3 times

Comment: After you uninstall it, did you confirm that the installation directory is empty? Do you have any antivirus software running? (try disabling it)

Comment: no anti virus just regular old windows defender

Comment: Since the other user got the same error, consider reporting this to https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/

Answer (score 7):

As I found there 2 solutions for this error. Try both :

**Solution : 1**

1. C:\Users\your_account_name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MSYS2 64bit
2. Run "MSYS2 MSYS" as **administrator**
3. Run the command : **pacman -Syu**

**Solution - 2** :

1. C:\msys64\var\lib\pacman ( Go to the downloaded folder)
2. Delete the **"db.lck"** file

---

RESOURCES :

For solution 1 : Mr. Padro's (https://stackoverflow.com/users/18910613/pedro) solution helped me.

For solution 2
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/nvrny2/pacman_error_failed_to_synchronize_all_databases/

Answer (score 5):

Try to run MSYS app under administrator privilege... worked for me